# missing /bin folder inside conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtualenv

I created a conda environment using following command:

```
conda create -p D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users python=3.7 pip -y
```

But noticed that when I activate the environment then try to pip install a new package I get Access Denied (as if it was trying to install in ProgramData instead of inside the environment)

Then I noticed that **the `/bin/` folder is missing** (see [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html) that clearly states there should be a bin folder in a conda environment). **Any idea why?**

EDIT: 
I also tried `where pip` 
before activating environment, 
it gives

```
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe
```

After activating the environment, it gives (in this order)

```
D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe
```

### Environment Information

`conda info`

```
     active environment : D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users
    active env location : D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users
            shell level : 1
       user config file : D:\Users\_azbatchtask_14\.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          D:\Users\_azbatchtask_14\.conda\pkgs
                          D:\Users\_azbatchtask_14\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : D:\Users\_azbatchtask_14\.conda\envs
                          C:\Anaconda3\envs
                          D:\Users\_azbatchtask_14\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

`conda list --show-channel-urls`

```
# packages in environment at D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0    defaults
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_0    defaults
openssl                   1.1.1c               he774522_1    defaults
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0    defaults
python                    3.7.3                h8c8aaf0_1    defaults
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.28.0               he774522_0    defaults
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4    defaults
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4    defaults
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0    defaults
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0    defaults
```

Find below the structure I have

```
Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:29 PM            22,280 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            21,256 api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,184 api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            22,792 api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            27,912 api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            26,888 api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            71,432 api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            23,304 api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            24,840 api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            24,840 api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            21,256 api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           329,368 concrt140.dll
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          conda-meta
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          DLLs
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          include
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          Lib
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          Library
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          libs
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,769 LICENSE_PYTHON.txt
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           625,808 msvcp140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM            31,896 msvcp140_1.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           195,248 msvcp140_2.dll
04/24/2019  08:30 PM            95,232 python.exe
04/24/2019  08:30 PM           438,272 python.pdb
04/24/2019  08:30 PM            51,712 python3.dll
04/24/2019  08:30 PM         3,745,792 python37.dll
04/24/2019  08:30 PM         9,523,200 python37.pdb
04/24/2019  08:30 PM            93,696 pythonw.exe
04/24/2019  08:30 PM           438,272 pythonw.pdb
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          Scripts
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          tcl
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          Tools
04/20/2018  01:37 PM         1,016,584 ucrtbase.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           386,720 vccorlib140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           155,280 vcomp140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM            87,200 vcruntime140.dll
              56 File(s)     18,091,625 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  69,282,779,136 bytes free
"\Lib" 
 Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Lib

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,580 abc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            32,814 aifc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               477 antigravity.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            95,103 argparse.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,575 ast.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,328 asynchat.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          asyncio
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,118 asyncore.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,380 base64.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            31,489 bdb.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            13,954 binhex.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,557 bisect.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,410 bz2.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            24,826 calendar.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            34,549 cgi.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,018 cgitb.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,435 chunk.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            14,860 cmd.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            10,619 code.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            36,287 codecs.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,994 codeop.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          collections
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             4,064 colorsys.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            13,649 compileall.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          concurrent
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            54,283 configparser.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,774 contextlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               129 contextvars.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,815 copy.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,017 copyreg.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,805 cProfile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,346 crypt.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            16,180 csv.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ctypes
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          curses
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            48,508 dataclasses.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            86,298 datetime.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          dbm
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               320 decimal.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            84,387 difflib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            19,888 dis.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          distutils
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           104,284 doctest.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,815 dummy_threading.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          email
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          encodings
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ensurepip
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            34,778 enum.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             9,830 filecmp.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            14,568 fileinput.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             4,056 fnmatch.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            15,143 formatter.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,639 fractions.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            35,257 ftplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            32,441 functools.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             4,756 genericpath.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,489 getopt.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,994 getpass.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            21,967 gettext.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,638 glob.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,338 gzip.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             9,534 hashlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,017 heapq.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,517 hmac.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          html
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          http
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          idlelib
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            53,292 imaplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,795 imghdr.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            10,536 imp.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          importlib
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           117,615 inspect.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,517 io.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            75,072 ipaddress.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          json
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,245 keyword.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          lib2to3
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,312 linecache.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            78,027 locale.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          logging
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,983 lzma.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,123 macpath.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            78,654 mailbox.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,104 mailcap.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,880 mimetypes.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,035 modulefinder.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          msilib
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          multiprocessing
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,566 netrc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            43,088 nntplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            22,340 ntpath.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,584 nturl2path.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            10,244 numbers.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,824 opcode.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            10,863 operator.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            60,371 optparse.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            37,756 os.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            49,389 pathlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            62,544 pdb.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            57,837 pickle.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            91,220 pickletools.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,916 pipes.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            21,461 pkgutil.py
04/24/2019  07:46 PM            47,067 platform.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            29,885 plistlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            14,964 poplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            15,772 posixpath.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,884 pprint.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            22,046 profile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            27,313 pstats.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             4,763 pty.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            15,137 pyclbr.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           106,731 pydoc.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          pydoc_data
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,001 py_compile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,359 queue.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,254 quopri.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            27,557 random.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            15,192 re.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,267 reprlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,097 rlcompleter.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,959 runpy.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,442 sched.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,038 secrets.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            18,561 selectors.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,527 shelve.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,956 shlex.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            41,329 shutil.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,123 signal.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          site-packages
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            21,649 site.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            34,711 smtpd.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            44,210 smtplib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,086 sndhdr.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            27,363 socket.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            26,922 socketserver.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          sqlite3
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            26,872 sre_compile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,177 sre_constants.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            39,305 sre_parse.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            45,432 ssl.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,038 stat.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,651 statistics.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,564 string.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            12,917 stringprep.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               257 struct.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            69,966 subprocess.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            18,375 sunau.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             2,131 symbol.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,274 symtable.py
04/24/2019  07:46 PM            24,649 sysconfig.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            24,317 sysconfig.py.orig
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            11,408 tabnanny.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            92,617 tarfile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,135 telnetlib.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            26,710 tempfile.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          test
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            19,494 textwrap.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             1,003 this.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            48,104 threading.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            13,444 timeit.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          tkinter
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,763 token.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            27,030 tokenize.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            28,543 trace.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,438 traceback.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            17,076 tracemalloc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               879 tty.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           143,602 turtle.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          turtledemo
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             9,897 types.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            54,602 typing.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          unittest
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          urllib
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,816 uu.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            29,449 uuid.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          venv
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,242 warnings.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            18,229 wave.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            20,689 weakref.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            23,097 webbrowser.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          wsgiref
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,913 xdrlib.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          xml
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          xmlrpc
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,535 zipapp.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            80,379 zipfile.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             1,801 _bootlocale.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            26,424 _collections_abc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             8,749 _compat_pickle.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,340 _compression.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,117 _dummy_thread.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            14,598 _markupbase.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            19,138 _osx_support.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM           228,535 _pydecimal.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            91,166 _pyio.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             6,186 _py_abc.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             3,115 _sitebuiltins.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM            25,504 _strptime.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             7,214 _threading_local.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,679 _weakrefset.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM             5,101 __future__.py
03/25/2019  08:21 PM                64 __phello__.foo.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          __pycache__
             172 File(s)      4,330,005 bytes
              34 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
"\Lib\site-packages" 
 Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Lib\site-packages

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          certifi
06/20/2019  10:54 PM             2,990 certifi-2019.06.16-py3.7.egg-info
04/23/2019  01:18 AM               126 easy_install.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          pip
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          pip-19.1.1-py3.7.egg-info
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          pkg_resources
03/25/2019  08:21 PM               119 README.txt
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          setuptools
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          setuptools-41.0.1-py3.7.egg-info
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          wheel
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          wheel-0.33.4-py3.7.egg-info
06/28/2018  10:27 PM             5,788 wincertstore-0.2-py3.7.egg-info
10/23/2013  07:30 AM            11,873 wincertstore.py
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          __pycache__
               5 File(s)         20,896 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
```

"\Library" 
     Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
     Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

```
 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Library

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          bin
05/29/2019  06:11 PM               412 ct_log_list.cnf
05/29/2019  06:11 PM               412 ct_log_list.cnf.dist
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          include
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          lib
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          misc
05/29/2019  06:11 PM            10,909 openssl.cnf
05/29/2019  06:11 PM            10,909 openssl.cnf.dist
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ssl
               4 File(s)         22,642 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
"\Library\bin" 
 Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\Library\bin

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:28 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:29 PM            22,280 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            21,256 api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,184 api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            18,696 api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            22,792 api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            20,744 api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            27,912 api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            26,888 api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            71,432 api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,720 api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            23,304 api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            24,840 api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            24,840 api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            21,256 api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
04/20/2018  01:37 PM            19,208 api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           329,368 concrt140.dll
06/27/2019  04:29 AM             6,548 c_rehash.pl
05/29/2019  06:11 PM         3,407,360 libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
05/29/2019  06:11 PM        10,088,448 libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb
05/29/2019  06:11 PM           681,472 libssl-1_1-x64.dll
05/29/2019  06:11 PM         2,322,432 libssl-1_1-x64.pdb
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           625,808 msvcp140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM            31,896 msvcp140_1.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           195,248 msvcp140_2.dll
05/29/2019  06:11 PM           542,720 openssl.exe
05/29/2019  06:11 PM         2,527,232 openssl.pdb
04/22/2019  06:33 PM         1,028,608 sqlite3.dll
04/22/2019  06:33 PM         1,303,552 sqlite3.exe
04/20/2018  01:37 PM         1,016,584 ucrtbase.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           386,720 vccorlib140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM           155,280 vcomp140.dll
11/13/2018  04:56 PM            87,200 vcruntime140.dll
              57 File(s)     25,601,052 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
 Volume in drive D is Temporary Storage
 Volume Serial Number is 2AF3-E29E

 Directory of D:\batch\tasks\shared\test-condaenv-users\libs

06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          .
06/27/2019  04:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/24/2019  08:30 PM           170,564 python3.lib
04/24/2019  08:29 PM           342,616 python37.lib
04/24/2019  08:30 PM             1,750 _tkinter.lib
               3 File(s)        514,930 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  69,282,762,752 bytes free
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

not sure of how the -p flag works as I have never used it but using -n flag seems to fix the error.

To create an environment with a specific version of Python:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```

To create an environment with a specific package:

```
conda create -n myenv scipy
```

conda [official docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.1/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) to manage environments.

Comment: Is it also applicable for python 3.9, it performed the upper command through powershell, but still I have no bin folder under user/anaconda34 and I want to use 'base' environment of conda..

Comment: how this answer gets upvoted?! it is completely irrelevant. the question is about -p, which installs the env in a non-default directory. and yes, as i also experienced, there is no bin/python in the newly installed env.